# Given $0<r<1$ irrational, there exists a $C^\infty$-homeomorphism $f\colon (a,b)\to(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ such that $|f|^r$ is $C^\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

When $r$ is a rational number $p/q$ with $q$ odd, for example, the answer is affirmative using bump functions such that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (vanishing the distinct lateral derivatives of $|\cdot|$ at $0$ by chain rule), as with the $C^\infty$-homeomorphism $f\colon\left(-\sqrt{-1/\ln\varepsilon},\sqrt{-1/\ln\varepsilon}\right)\to(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ definded by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-q/x^2}& \text{ if }x>0,\\
              0 &\text{ if }x=0, \\
              -e^{-q/x^2}&\text{ if }x<0\end{cases}.$$

But I'm stuck when q is even, or the main case when r is irrational (and more difficult). I would appreciate any hint.

Comment: You can make do with just $f(x)=\operatorname{sgn}(x)e^{-x^{-2}}$. Actually, $\lvert f\rvert^r$ will be $C^\infty$ for all $r>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function \begin{align}&f:(-a,a)\to (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\\ &f(x)=\begin{cases}\varepsilon e^{a^{-2}}\cdot e^{-x^{-2}}&\text{if }x>0\\ -\varepsilon e^{a^{-2}}\cdot e^{-x^{-2}}&\text{if }x<0\\ 0&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}\end{align}

is a $C^\infty$ homeomorphism, and $\lvert f(x)\rvert^r=\begin{cases}\varepsilon^re^{ra^{-2}}\cdot e^{-rx^{-2}}&\text{if }x\ne 0\\ 0&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$ is $C^\infty$ for all $r>0$. The proof is the same as proving that $e^{-x^{-2}}$ is $C^\infty$: you prove that for all $n$ there is a rational function $g_n$ such that the denominator of $g_n$ is a power of $x$ and such that $(\lvert f\rvert^r)^{(n)}(x)=\begin{cases}g_n(x)e^{-rx^{-2}}&\text{if }x\ne0\\ 0&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$. In order to do that, you can proceed iteratively by proving at each step that $(\lvert f\rvert^r)^{(n)}$ is continuous at $0$ and $C^1$ on $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, and then that $\lim_{x\to 0} (\lvert f\rvert^r)^{(n+1)}(x)=0$.

You can obtain a $C^\infty$ homeomorphism $(a,b)\to(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ by using $f(x-(b+a)/2)$, where $f:\left(\frac{a-b}2,\frac{b-a}2\right)\to(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!